# How to prevent access to my website via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a JavaScript function to check a condition, and if that is True then I deny access to the code? Right now I am checking the user agent, and if it doesn't meet given criteria then I delete the HTML tag. However, if they go to the network tab then they can still see the GET requests and responses for my code.

This is a website running on localhost because it's an Electron app by the way.

I thought maybe I could issue a 403 error but I'm not sure if that's possible via JS.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about server-side JS or the usual client stuff (HTML with `<script>` tags, etc)?

Comment: @melpomene Well it's only running on localhost so I think just normal JS?

Comment: whats hes asking is if the javascript runs on the server or on the client. if it runs on the client its never possible. it is however if the code runs on the server.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The server and the client are still different programs (that communicate over HTTP), even if they're on the same physical machine.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason for this. It's an Electron app. It's all running on the end user's machine. So why are you trying to hide the transfer of data between two processes on that machine from the user? What's the actual end goal?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It might be based on an incorrect assumption that it is possible to include the files in an executable. I can prevent them from opening the console within the app, so if I can also prevent them from seeing the code in their browser then I can hide it all from them.

Comment: @melpomene I don't know, if either is possible and only server works, then how do I do that?

Comment: @FJ - But what's the ultimate goal? To hide your code from people downloading your Electron app?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes

Answer (score 0):

In an Electron app, your code is still JavaScript source code. You can obfuscate it and/or put it in a ASAR archive to make it harder to read and fine, but the code is still there and accessible to anyone who wants to go to the effort. (For instance, if you use VS Code, you can see the source in `resources/app/out` directory and its subdirectories.)

You can make it even harder to find and understand the source if you're willing to put in more work. V8, the JavaScript engine Node.js uses, has a feature called [startup snapshots](https://v8.dev/blog/custom-startup-snapshots): You run V8 and have it load your script (your obfuscated code), take a heap snapshot (after GC), and write it to a file. Then you specify the heap snapshot when loading V8, and it just hauls in the snapshot instead of reading and parsing code. The [Atom team have done this](https://blog.atom.io/2017/04/18/improving-startup-time.html) on top of Electron. In their case the motivation was startup performance, not hiding the source code, but it has the effect of making your code even harder to find.

Note I said harder, not impossible. At the end of the day, if you want the code to execute on the end-user's computer, that code is going to be accessible to the end user. This is true even of compiled applications, although of course in that case a lot of organizational information that helps a human understand the code is lost in compilation, which happens less with obfuscated code. (But a good obfuscator makes code extremely opaque to human beings.)